# CSS rotating image is not working

Tags: html, css, image, rotation

So I have been trying to rotate a jpeg image in css for a while. The image is inside a p tag. What I am trying to do is to rotate the image and I want text file to wrap the image and not touch it. I managed to do the wrapping part but for some odd reason when I try to rotate the image it only rotates the background of the image. The actual image is not rotating. Here is the html code:

```
   <p><img src="Image.jpg" alt = "A picture of Jose"> 
      Some text
   </p>

    p img{
        float: right;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 200px;
        height: auto;
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        position: relative;
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking - the image does rotate - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/obVwoq

Comment: Working fine for me... https://jsfiddle.net/o3kzrwz6/2/

Comment: Working fine for me too: [https://jsfiddle.net/thhznLx9/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/thhznLx9/1/)... If you're adding comments in the way you have in your question then that might be the problem as if I add them exactly the same way as you have: `// comments`, it breaks: [https://jsfiddle.net/thhznLx9/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/thhznLx9/3/) CSS comments are `/*** Comment ***/`

Answer (score 0):

As [David Wilkinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4004172/david-wilkinson) wrote, CSS support just /* ... */ comments, not // so if you use the last one it break the style.
Try this instead:

```
    /* Here is the CSS */
    p img{
        float: right;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 200px;
        height: auto;
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        position: relative;
        display: block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, its just that you are using this `//Here is the css:` for comment instead of `/*Here is the css*/`

if you want to check, try having your code like this

```
<style>
p img{
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

// Here is the CSS:
</style>
```

Now this code will work but any other `css` code that comes after `// Here is the CSS:` will not work. so for comments in css use this `/* css comment */`